# Container BlendMode disappears when scrolling a listview - Flutter

Tags: flutter, blend-mode

I'm trying to apply a backgroundBlendMode to a Container using its decoration attribute, the Container is inside a listview, when running the app everything looks as expected until scrolling the listview, the blend mode disappears and the color is displayed as is.

here is the code for the decoration:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.black,
  backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.overlay,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(_contentBorderRadius),
    topRight: Radius.circular(_contentBorderRadius),
  ),
  border: Border.all(color: lightGreen, width: _contentBorderWidth),
),
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem but with videos.